# What's the meaning of [class.notvalid] in code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Iam a pretty new in Angular , please help with the following code in Angular. 
We have a special window which checks the customer data. You put special bill number and then POPup will show and you must enter the card number. But when we put incorrect card number to the input field (which he cant find in backend), the POPup dissepares and it shouldn't work this way. The POPup window should stay and you can put another card number for checking the card. I guess the problem is with validation may be Im not sure but I guess the valdiation is related to  [class.notvalid]
But I dont know the meaning of the code [class.notvalid]. Please explain if you can the meaning of the [class.notvalid]

I have a Angular CLI: 8.3.5 versioun . It was hard to me to try to correct the code as I cant understand some modules in Angular

transfer.html

```
            <p class="input-label" [translate]="'page.transfers.RECIPIENT_IIN_BIN'" [class.notvalid]="iin && !finn?.valid">IIN/BIN of customer</p>
            <div class="input-w"
                 [class.input-w-error]="recipient !== undefined && !recipient.success">
              <input type="tel" maxlength="12" class="input"
                     #finn="ngModel"
                     [(ngModel)]="iin"
                     (keyup)="searchRecipientOtherBank(iin, iban)"
                     [class.notvalid]="iin && !finn?.valid"
                     pattern="^[0-9]{0,12}$"
                     require/>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I expect that when you put the card number the POPup will not dissaper and you can try to put another number

Comment: If the condition `iin && !finn?.valid` is true angular will add `notvalid` class to classlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[class.input-w-error]` and `[class.notvalid]` are angular directives to access css classes in the format -("class.css-class-name").

The class is used when the condition assigned evaluates true.
In the code above-
`[class.notvalid]="iin && !finn?.valid"`

`.notvalid` class is added to the classes if `iin && !finn?.valid` evaluates true.